# xml parsing geodata and place on map

Tags: xml, google-maps

I did JS program which gets all of the geo data points from an XML file using an AJAX call. Now I need to take these points and place them on a google map. I did all the coding for the map and getting it to show up etc and I do have long and lat numbers from my XML but how can I insert those numbers in the map so the points will show up?

Answer (score 0):

An example from google at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Marker Simple</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng, 
        map: map,
        title:"Hello World!"
    });   
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are alot of examples of how to use the map api at:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html

Comment: Yea I have that code and it worked, my issue here is that when I have 50 geo points and I want them all to be plotted on the map. The AJAX call returns a list of geo points and I want to point all of those points

Comment: Can you please post a portion of your list returned from the ajax call and I'll update my answer to fit that.

Comment: function myHelper(){
             $('.result tr:last ').after('<tr><td>' + $('geo\\:lat', this).text() + '</td><td>' + $('geo\\:long', this).text() + '</td><td>');
              
        
   }


$(document).ready(function()
    {
        // reading in XML
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://students.ics.uci.edu/~oahmad/myProxy.php?http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=USCA0517&u=f",
            dataType: "rss",
            success: processXML,
            error: errorXML
        });
    }

)